# Не могу найти ошибку в синтаксисе

Tags: php

```
    if ($page != 1){ $pstr_prev = '<li><a class="pstr-prev" href="index.php?page='.($page - 1).'">&lt;</a></li>';} 
        if ($page != $total){ $pstr_next = '<li><a class="pstr-next" href="index.php?page='.($page + 1).'">&lt;</a></li>';}

        if($page - 5 > 0) $page5left = '<li><a href="index.php?page'.($page - 5).'">'.($page - 5).'</a></li>';
        if($page - 4 > 0) $page4left = '<li><a href="index.php?page'.($page - 4).'">'.($page - 4).'</a></li>';
        if($page - 3 > 0) $page3left = '<li><a href="index.php?page'.($page - 3).'">'.($page - 3).'</a></li>';
        if($page - 2 > 0) $page2left = '<li><a href="index.php?page'.($page - 2).'">'.($page - 2).'</a></li>';
        if($page - 1 > 0) $page1left = '<li><a href="index.php?page'.($page - 1).'">'.($page - 1).'</a></li>';

        if($page + 5 <= $total) $page5right = '<li><a href="index.php?page'.($page + 5).'">'.($page + 5).'</a></li>';
        if($page + 4 <= $total) $page4right = '<li><a href="index.php?page'.($page + 4).'">'.($page + 4).'</a></li>';
        if($page + 3 <= $total) $page3right = '<li><a href="index.php?page'.($page + 3).'">'.($page + 3).'</a></li>';
        if($page + 2 <= $total) $page2right = '<li><a href="index.php?page'.($page + 2).'">'.($page + 2).'</a></li>';
        if($page + 1 <= $total) $page1right = '<li><a href="index.php?page'.($page + 1).'">'.($page + 1).'</a></li>';

        if ($page+5 < $total)
        {
            $strtotal = '<li><p class="nav-point">...</p></li><li><a href="index.php?page='.$total.'">'.$total.'</a></li>';

        }else 

        {
          $strtotal = "";  
        } 

        if ($total > 1)

        {

            echo '
            <div class="pstrnav">
            <ul>
            ';
           echo  $pstr_prev.$page5left.$page4left.$page3left.$page2left.$page1left."<li><a class='pstr-active' href='index.php?page=".$page."'>".$page."</a></li>".$page1right.$page2right.$page3right.$page4right.$page5right.$strtotal.$pstr_next ;
            echo '
            </ul>
            </div>
            ';
        }
```

Запрос:

```
      $num= 12;
    $page = (int)$_GET['page'];

    $count = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM  `table_product` WHERE visible='1' ");
    $temp = mysqli_fetch_array($count);

    if ($temp[0]> 0)
    {
        $tempcoount = $temp[0];

         $total = (($tempcount - 1) / $num)+ 1;
         $total = intval($total);

         $page = intval($page);

         if(empty($page) or $page < 0) $page = 1;
         if($page > $total) $page = $total;

         $start = $page * $num - $num;

         $qury_start_num = "LIMIT $start, $num";
    }
                $result =  mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM  `table_product` WHERE visible='1'  ORDER BY $sorting  $qury_start_num ");
  (!!!!116!!!!)              if  (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
                  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
               echo('
```

Comment: Сама ошибка:
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '?'

Comment: она явно не тут. с этой строкой все норм

Comment: может точка с запятой или лишняя кавычка в строке(строках) выше

Comment: Я добавил весь код.Посмотрите,пожалуйста

Comment: тут тоже все норм)

Comment: Тогда что может быть ?(((

Comment: Вот же,когда убираю эту строку он мне показывает ошибку в запросе!
Ошибка в 116 строке:
Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in

Сам запрос добавил

Comment: @Виталий ну а теперь сравните какую вы вначале ошибку пишите, а какую сейчас и в каком месте.

Comment: У вас ошибка в запросе `$result` вставьте в 116 строку `var_dump("SELECT * FROM  table_product WHERE visible='1'  ORDER BY $sorting  $qury_start_num "); exit;` и покажите результат

Comment: Ее заменить нужно?
Если заменить,то выходит:
string(85) "SELECT * FROM table_product WHERE visible='1' ORDER BY product_id DESC LIMIT -12, 12 "

Comment: откуда у вас взялся отрицателньый лимит? вот поэтому и ошибка

Comment: Проблемы, которые решает любая современная IDE на 99% теперь задают на SO. Куда катится мир.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
$result =  mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM  `table_product` WHERE visible='1'  ORDER BY " . $sorting . " LIMIT " . $start . ", " . $num);
```

И, кстати, где у вас переменная `$sorting` объявляется?